# Notification inbox style

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I wanted to create something like an instant messaging application. How do I display multiple messages all in one notification? I can create a notification that appear when user receive a single notification. But when the user receive more than one message how can I update the notification with the previous message? Should I save the messages into a database and display it out if the user did not cancel the notification? Or is there any other way that I can handle this?

Below is my notification code.

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "IMTest- A new event is created" , when);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, IM_Chat.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("topicId", topicId);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("sender", sender);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, topicName, "A new event ["+eventName+"] is added in "+topicName, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.ledARGB |= 0xff0000ff;
    notification.ledOffMS |= 1000;
    notification.ledOnMS |= 300;
    notificationManager.notify(CommunitiesappConstant.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update notification using same id and builder

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating

```
 private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  private mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  //Different Id's will show up as different notifications
  private int mNotificationId = 1;    
  //Some things we only have to set the first time.
  private boolean firstTime = true;

  private updateNotification(String message, int progress) {
    if (firstTime) {
      mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
      .setContentTitle("My Notification")
      .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
      firstTime = false;
    }
    mBuilder.setContentText(message)
    .setProgress(100, progress, true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try it out! But how can I check whether the notification exists in the first place before I update it?

Comment: I tried this and I only managed to create a compact notification for one message. How can i implement this for inbox notification style?